# Symfony Doctrine Native Query Result Mapping Joining Subquery select

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have problem with symfony and doctrine creating native query, when I try to map results of a Joining a subquery select. I get null result for joined fields for ex. ad.availability is null .

Basicly I have 2 tables  activities and activity_dates. I need to get minimum price of each activity. SQL work right. but stuck in mapping.

Any Idea?

thanks

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('ActivityBundle:Activity', 'ac');
$rsm->addEntityResult('ActivityBundle:ActivityDate', 'ad');
$rsm->addFieldResult('ac', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('ac', 'title', 'title');
$rsm->addFieldResult('ad','availability','availability');


$sql = 'SELECT 
            ac.id,
            ac.title,
            ac.price,
            ad.availability
        FROM
            activities ac
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT 
                id,
                date,
                price,
                activity_id,
                availability
            FROM
                activity_dates a
            WHERE
                price = (
                    SELECT 
                        MIN(price)
                    FROM
                        activity_dates b
                    WHERE
                        b.activity_id = a.activity_id
                )
            ) ad
        ON
            ad.activity_id =  ac.id';


$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm)
    ->setHint(
        \Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER,
        'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker'
    )
    ->setHint(
        \Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener::HINT_INNER_JOIN,
        true
    );
```

Comment: if you run the query without doctrine manually filling in the values does it return what you would expect?

Comment: yes it does.  sql query returns the correct  values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start off by simplifying the query:

```
SELECT ac.id, ac.title, ac.price, ad.availability
FROM activities ac
LEFT JOIN activity_dates ad
    ON ad.activity_id = ac.id
LEFT JOIN activity_dates ad2
    ON ad2.activity_id = ad.activity_id
        AND ad2.price < ad.price
WHERE ad2.price IS NULL
```

The self-join to activity_dates will try to fetch records from ad2 that have a lower price than the one in ad. This will of course fail when the price in ad is the lowest available, so the record from ac2 will be empty. This is what we can use to reduce the result via `ad2.price IS NULL`.

What I don't quite understand: In your query you compare prices of activity_dates, but select the price of the activity. If you want the lowest price for every activity, you need to compare prices of activities, not activity_dates. Or if you wanted the cheapest activity_date, then you would need to select ad.price instead. Maybe it's just a typo...

Anyways: With this simplified query, you should be able to create your entities in a useful manner and then just use the query functions of doctrine. No need to do custom queries here.

For reference on self-joins, please see the doctrine documentation: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-self-referencing

Or perhaps this SO post:
[Doctrine 2 Self Join Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048438/doctrine-2-self-join-query)

Basically it boils down to a query like this (adopted from a Symfony 3 project):

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('ac');
$query->select('ac.id, ac.title, ac.price, ad.availability')
    ->leftJoin('ac.activityDates', 'ad')
    ->leftJoin('ad.selfJoin', 'ad2', Join::WITH, 'ad2.price < ad.price')
    ->where(
        $query->expr()->isNull('ad2.price')
    );
$result = $query->getQuery()->getResult(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: thanks for answer I will try and tell you the result. about activity and dates , every activity has different prices for different days,

Comment: Well, personally I would want to see ad.price in that case. But it's up to you and only a very small change. Did the simplification do the trick?

Comment: @Never: If my answer helped you solving the problem, please consider marking it as the accepted answer or at least upvote it. If it didn't, feel free to add comments, so I can help you resolve any issues. Thanks.